# How to pass Hadoop credentials provider path to Map Reduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, credentials

I am storing my S3 credentials with Hadoop Security credentials provider.

When I run `distcp` I can pass the path to credentials provider like this:

`-Dfs.s3a.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/foo/bar/s3.jceks`

I'd like to do the same for a Map Reduce job, so it can write directly to S3.

I've tried setting this property 
`configuration.set("fs.s3a.security.credential.provider.path", "path_to_provider");`

in my Map Reduce job, but that did not work.

And yes, I am aware that I can pass them in clear text from the terminal or store them in clear text in `core-site.xml`, and the reason why I ask this question is exactly because I don't want to do that.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: did you set ```hadoop.security.credential.provider.path```? Not sure if it is required though. I was just reading this: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configure_the_hadoop.security.credential.provider.path_property

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, yes, I did that, and I even tried to set it up with multiple credentials providers. (One credential provider for each bucket) But unfortunately  this did not seem to work. This will only pick up the first credentials provider from the chain and will ignore others. (I guess this is to do with AWS S3 specifically). I've also tried to create alias like this ```fs.s3a.bucket-name.access.key
fs.s3a.bucket-name.secret.key``` within credentials provider but that did not seem to work either. So my problem is that this works only with one bucket.

Comment: Did you try to set `hadoop.security.credential.provider.path` inside `core-site.xml`? 
please update the question with the exact error you get.